# EDIT-How can I have my specific format using Object.entries?

Tags: reactjs

I have these data from my api (1) and the format I want to have is this one(2), how can I do that in my front-end using `Object.entries` in REACT, in such a way I can modify my (1) to have (2) please ? I tried but not working...

(1):

```
  {
        "myData": [
            {
                "Peter": 12,
                "Donald": 15,
                "Huston": 65
            }
        ],
        "myOtherData": [
            {
                "location": "Dublin",
                "country":"Irland"
            }
        ]
    }
```

(2):

```
{
        "myData": [
            {
                "name": "Peter",
                "age": "12"
            },
            {
                "name": "Donald",
                "age": "15"
            },
            {
                "name": "Huston",
                "age": "65"
            }
        ],
        "myOtherData": [
            {
                "location": "Dublin",
                "country":"Irland"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I was thinking using destructuration like this :

```
const d= {myData, myOtherData}
const newData = Object.entries(...)//change myData here ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets be fancy, time to utilise flatMap, array deconstruction and some shortcuts

```js
const a = {
  "myData": [{
    "Peter": 12,
    "Donald": 15,
    "Huston": 65
  }]
}

console.log({
  myData: Object.entries(a.myData[0])
    .flatMap(([name, age]) => ({
      name,
      age
    }))
})
```

Comment: you're not using e : `flatMap(([name,age]=e)..` ? So `e` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

```js
const resp = {
  "myData": [{
    "Peter": 12,
    "Donald": 15,
    "Huston": 65
  }]
}

convertedData = []
for (const person of Object.entries(resp.myData[0])) {
  convertedData.push({
    name: person[0],
    age: person[1]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  "myData": [{
    "Peter": 12,
    "Donald": 15,
    "Huston": 65
  }]
}

console.log( 
  Object.entries(data.myData[0])
  .reduce( (acc,[name,age])=>acc.concat({name,age}),[] ) 
)
```

Comment: when I refresh the page i got a blank page... I've edited my question a bit since I'm continuing my code

Answer (score 0):

lets say

```
   var myData = {
            "Peter": 12,
            "Donald": 15,
            "Huston": 65
        }
    var finalData = Object.entries(myData).map(entry => {
      const[key,value] = entry;
      return {
        name:key,
        age:value
      }  
    })
    console.log(finalData)
```